# How apple knows the ip address of the device for sending push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

How apple knows the **IP address** of the target device to send the push notification...

1. APN server needs **p12 certificate, provisioning profile** and **token id** to send the push notification. Any way If a server send a information or data to the client(Actually apple device) It should have a **IP address** of the client. How APN server knows this?
2. or apple devices should **poll** APN server for notification.Any other trick is followed behind APN service?

Comment: Apple send push notification based on the device id.For more details please refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Device token is unique for the devices,So device token is needed for the push notification

Comment: @AlbinJoseph I have read that document many times... But My question is how the apple knows the ip address of the device?

Comment: @Rose No. After finding device identity. How the apple establishes the communication channel between specific device?

Answer (score 2):

From ["Apple Push Notification Service"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)
in the "Local and Push Notification Programming Guide":

> Each device establishes an accredited and encrypted IP connection
>   with the service and receives notifications over this persistent
>   connection.

So it is the *device* that initiates the connection to APNs. Therefore the APNs need
not know the device's IP address.

Comment: Thank you...Any document about this accredited and encrypted IP connection to understand better.